# Как кроссбраузерно добавить адаптивное видео в контейнере, но с фоном на всю ширину экрана?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, видео

Есть `video` с прозрачным постером, описанием и фоновой картинкой к нему на всю ширину.

В `chrome` все смотрится так, как и задумано, только хотелось бы, чтобы воспроизведение видео начиналось при клике на любую его область, в том числе и описание.

Но, в `firefox` и `edge` все выглядит иначе - бекграунд плеера сплошной черный, а не прозрачный и не видно самого описания. Как это исправить?

**Код:**

```css
#video {
  background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zf-GMvFd154/maxresdefault.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
 position:relative;
}  
#video .video-description {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    max-width: 550px;
    font-weight:bold;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <section id="video">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="video-description">
        <h4>Lovely Video</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta dignissimos, asperiores corrupti quaerat ea sequi. </p>
        <span>00:10</span>
      </div>
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <video class="embed-responsive-item " width="100%" controls poster="data:image/gif,AAAA">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно при нажатии на секцию показвыать видео (изначально скрыто) и запускать

```js
document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("click", function()
{
  document.getElementById("video-inside").play();
  document.getElementById("video-inside").style = "";
});
```

```css
#video {
  background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zf-GMvFd154/maxresdefault.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
 position:relative;
}  
#video .video-description {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    max-width: 550px;
    font-weight:bold;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <section id="video">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="video-description">
        <h4>Lovely Video</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta dignissimos, asperiores corrupti quaerat ea sequi. </p>
        <span>00:10</span>
      </div>
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <video class="embed-responsive-item " id="video-inside" width="100%" poster="data:image/gif,AAAA" style="display:none;">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```